# How would I find the cordinates as ints

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to turn a string into a grid where I can extract points based on chars I request I want it to return int x and int y

```
String map = ""+
"--------\n"+
"|   R* |\n"+
"| F    |\n"+
"--------"

public void findCord(String map, char object)
{
   
   
    String lines[] = map.split("\\n");
    int getYCord = 0;
    int getXCord = 0;
    Point testPoint = new Point(getXCord, getYCord);
    for(int i =0; i< lines.length; i++)
    {
        if(lines[i].indexOf(object) != -1 )
        {
            getXCord = lines[i].indexOf(object);
            
        }
        if(lines[i].indexOf(object) == -1)
        {
            getYCord = getYCord +1;
        }
        testPoint = new Point(getXCord -1, getYCord -1);
    }
    System.out.println("Cords test: "+ testPoint);
```

assuming object = F
Output = Cord test: (1,2)
Now when I look for R
Output = Cord test: (4,2)

Comment: Is the code presented here given already by task which you should extend, or is it your attempt to get the coordinates?  What would you expect as coordinates in your example, e.g.  for `F`? Or for `*`?  Please clarify what is the expected output as example.

Comment: Your `for` loop seems to miss a closing curly-brace. Please pay attention to proper formatting and make sure that either the code compiles or mention compile-errors - we expect a [example].

Comment: You're using indexOf() wrong - indexOf is giving you the index of a string, not the other way around. What you want is charAt(index). Not sure the way you use indexOf() even compiles...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void findCord(String map, char object)
{
   
   
    String lines[] = map.split("\\n");
    int getYCord = 0;
    int getXCord = 0;
    Point testPoint = new Point(getXCord, getYCord);
    for(int i =0; i< lines.length; i++)
    {
        if(lines[i].indexOf(object) != -1 )
        {
            getXCord = lines[i].indexOf(object);
            getYCord = i;
            
        }
        testPoint = new Point(getXCord -1, getYCord);
    }
```

returns all the right cords reading from a string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).